# What does the "expand" option do in grunt-contrib-copy? The examples all use it but the docs say nothing about what it does

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

1. Here is the README and examples: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/blob/master/README.md.
2. Here is the relevant part of the code (that I apparently cannot understand) from https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/blob/master/tasks/copy.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

  var path = require('path');

  grunt.registerMultiTask('copy', 'Copy files.', function() {
    var kindOf = grunt.util.kindOf;

    var options = this.options({
      processContent: false,
      processContentExclude: []
    });

    var copyOptions = {
      process: options.processContent,
      noProcess: options.processContentExclude
    };

    grunt.verbose.writeflags(options, 'Options');

    var dest;
    var isExpandedPair;
    var tally = {
      dirs: 0,
      files: 0
    };

    this.files.forEach(function(filePair) {
      isExpandedPair = filePair.orig.expand || false;

      filePair.src.forEach(function(src) {
        if (detectDestType(filePair.dest) === 'directory') {
          dest = (isExpandedPair) ? filePair.dest : unixifyPath(path.join(filePair.dest, src));
        } else {
          dest = filePair.dest;
        }

        if (grunt.file.isDir(src)) {
          grunt.verbose.writeln('Creating ' + dest.cyan);
          grunt.file.mkdir(dest);
          tally.dirs++;
        } else {
          grunt.verbose.writeln('Copying ' + src.cyan + ' -> ' + dest.cyan);
          grunt.file.copy(src, dest, copyOptions);
          tally.files++;
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Are you aware that the accepted answer is incorrect? See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900435/384617).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Expand lets you specify whether you want to create the destination path in full (e.g: `/path/missing1/missing2`), or only create the last directory when its parent exists (`/path/existing/missing`).

Comment: Ah, so it's effectively the -p option to mkdir. Got it, thanks!

Comment: This answer is not correct. It is at best simplified.

Comment: -1. This is misleading - based on this answer I removed `expand: true`, figuring I didn't need it, and then my build stopped working.

Answer (score 84):

Since `expand` is a part of Grunt, and not specific for grunt-contrib-copy, information about it can be found in [Grunt's file configuration API](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically):

> Set `expand` to `true` to enable the following options:
>
> - `cwd` All `src` matches are relative to (but don't include) this path.
> - `src` Pattern(s) to match, relative to the `cwd`.
> - `dest` Destination path prefix.
> - `ext` Replace any existing extension with this value in generated `dest` paths.
> - `extDot` Used to indicate where the period indicating the extension is located. Can take either `'first'` (extension begins after the first period in the file name) or `'last'` (extension begins after the last period), and is set by default to `'first'`.
> - `flatten` Remove all path parts from generated `dest` paths.
> - `rename` This function is called for each matched `src` file, (after extension renaming and flattening). The `dest` and matched `src` path are passed in, and this function must return a new `dest` value. If the same `dest` is returned more than once, each `src` which used it will be added to an array of sources for it.

Additionally it seems like `dest` will always be considered to be a destination directory if setting `expand` to `true`.

Comment: Better answer. But is this not documented anywhere?

Comment: I actually found the documentation after looking a second time, and I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I added the usefull example provided in the doc. Its more clear now.