# HTMLmin - How to dynamically compress all files inside a certain folder

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

I want to minify all HTML pages and maintain the page's name and path on the `dist` folder. I want to loop through all folders.

The code below works fine but ONLY for the parent folder (which is this case `app/views`).

```
grunt.initConfig({
    htmlmin: {
        dev: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'app/views/**',
                src: '{,*/}*.html',
                dest: 'dist/views'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

As you can notice, I tried the magic star at the path `app/views/**` and had no luck.

This is my folder structure:

```
app/views/
├── page1.html
├── blocks
│   └── block.html
├── page2.html
└── page3.html
```

In my case, every template gets minified, except the ones under `app/views/blocks` folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cwd: 'app/views',
src: '**/*.html',
```

Comment: doesn't work. the same output. Still does not dig into folders inside `app/views/`

Comment: Works fine for me. What are your version of Grunt and htmlmin?

Comment: For future usage, include expand: true, in files[{}]

Comment: per @Billy's comment, here is an SO post explaining what `expand:true` does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977884/what-does-the-expand-option-do-in-grunt-contrib-copy-the-examples-all-use-it